# Creating a Custom Properties Tab in Blender 2.80

Tags: python, customization, properties

I have a suite of several addons that I grouped together in a custom tab in Blender 2.7x, assigning the bl_category to the name of my custom suit:

```
class Panel1(bpy.types.Panel):  # Blender 2.7x
    bl_label = "Panel 1"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "MyToolSuite"
```

In Blender 2.80, I would like to group the tools together in a new properties tab.  How can I create a custom properties tab?

The following works to put my panel inside an already-existing tab, but does not work to create a new tab to hold all my panels:

```
class Panel1(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel 1"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    # bl_context = "object"     # this puts my panel in the Object tab
    bl_context = "MyToolSuite"  # this does nothing?
```

What else needs to be done to create a new tab in Blender 2.80?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found anything that exposes the Properties Editor to allow us to make custom tabs yet - the existing ones are from an enumerated list that is pulled in from source I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've posted adds a tab to the *Tool Shelf*, not the *Properties*. [As far as I know you cannot add new tabs to the properties](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-add-a-new-tab-in-the-properties-editor/2954/9), you can however add tabs in the *3D View*.

[image]

In Blender 2.8 you need the following attributes to create your own tab:

```
bl_category = "Name of your tab"
bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
bl_region_type = "UI"
```

A minimal add-on that adds a panel in a separate tab:

```
import bpy

class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My own addon"
    bl_category = "Name of your tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="This is a label")


classes = (EXAMPLE_PT_panel,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: Screenshot of the custom panel]

Comment: Aha.  Since the Tool Shelf no longer exists as before in 2.80, I figured the next best place to put my tools was over with the Properties.  But your solution is better.  Thanks rjg!